# Python Base64 Selenium module missing when converting to exe

Tags: python, selenium, base64, pyinstaller

I have encoded my program so I can sell it to customers.

Also I want to convert it to exe with the tool auto-py-to-exe so the customers won't have to install python.

When I launch the encoded program from Visual Studio Code all works as intended.

But when I convert it to exe it returns an error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "test.py", line 8, in 
> File "", line 2, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
> [11189] Failed to execute script test
> logout

When I do not encode my program I can convert it without any issues.

Any idea what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was, to add the "import" lines for all my modules on the top level of the .py

Working now.